# Why did Regal reveal Fitz's plan to Kettricken and Rurisk?

Tags: realm-of-the-elderlings

In *Assassin's Apprentice*, the first book of the *Farseer Trilogy*, Fitz has a secret mission to kill [Prince Rurisk](http://robinhobbelderlings.wikia.com/wiki/Rurisk). Only Shrewd, Verity and Fitz seem to have knowledge of this.

When Fitz arrives in Jhaampe, Rurisk and Kettricken tell him that Regal told them that he came to kill Rurisk (hence the siblings try to posison Fitz).

I think this is a total mess and corrupts Farseer family interests.

1. How (or why) is Regal aware of this plan?
2. Why does he reveal it to the target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Spoilers for Assassin's Apprentice throughout:*

> I think this is a total mess and corrupts Farseer family interests.

That is true, but by that point in the books, it is already clear that Regal is working both

1. In his own interests before the Farseer interests, and
2. Actively against the Farseer interests to boot.

> How (or why) is Regal aware of this plan?

Presumably Shrewd told him... remember that Shrewd's decision to have Fitz assassinate Rurisk was rooted in a completely incorrect description of Rurisk, one that he had gotten from Regal:

> [Shrewd said] "The Princess has a single sibling, an older brother. 
>   He is not a healthy man.  Oh, he was well and strong once, but on the
>   Ice Fields he took an arrow through his chest.  Passed clean through
>   him, so Regal was told.  And the wounds on his back and chest healed. 
>   But in winters, he coughs blood, and in summer he cannot sit a horse
>   nor drill his men for more than half the morning."

In fact, as you'll see in a quote further down, Regal not only knew but actively requested a particular assassin.

> Why does he reveal it to the target?

Firstly, if there are two people Regal would like to see dead more than anyone else, it's Chade ("Lady Thyme") and FitzChivalry.  He believes Lady Thyme poisoned his mother, and has hated Fitz all the time he's known him.  So there is some likelihood that he led Shrewd to send an assassin specifically so that the assassin would be killed.  And he outright states he requested Lady Thyme:

> "No nerve," Regal observed with disgust.  "I asked Father to send that
>   old whore Lady Thyme.  She'd have had him in his grave by now."

Secondly, as we find out, Regal brought his own unsubtle poison for use against Rurisk.  By warning Rurisk and Kettricken of Fitz the Assassin, he lays a false trail to cover his own actions.  He can poison Rurisk and then credibly shift the blame to Fitz.

Had things worked out, Regal would have disposed of Rurisk, making Kettricken heir to the Mountain Kingdom, and then married her after Verity was murdered by Galen as planned.  With Kettricken and King Eyod led to believe that Shrewd's Assassin had killed Rurisk (and Regal no doubt protesting his innocence and inability to prevent that murder), Regal would have been well placed to receive the friendship of the Mountain Kingdom while ensuring their enmity against the Farseer line.  This is revealed in Regal's conversation with Galen:

> "Try to blame the bastard rather than Verity.  But not too
>   convincingly.  And tomorrow, when you are as bereaved as she
>   *[...after Verity is to be assassinated]*, well, we shall see what mutual sympathy leads to."
>
> "She is big as a cow and pale as a fish."
>
> "But with the mountain lands, you will have a defensible inland
>   kingdom.  You know the Coastal Duchies will not stand for you, and
>   Farrow and Tilth cannot stand alone between the mountains and the
>   Coastal Duchies.  Besides, she need not live longer than her first
>   child's birth."

...finally, recall that Regal does not see himself as a Farseer.  His mother often boasted that her bloodline was more royal than Shrewd's, and he sees himself as an inland duchy noble rather than a costal duchy Farseer.  Combined with his suspicion that Lady Thyme poisoned his mother on Shrewd Farseer's orders, and his actions become far more understandable.